# how can I render laravel mailable to variable

Tags: laravel

I need to get the html of a Mailable class

```
$mail->html = (new InactivityReminder())->"do something to output the html"
```

There seems to be no toHtml method or something similar.

Mailable:

```
class InactivityReminder extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('mail.it.inactivityReminder');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 5.5 the `render()` method will render the view that you return in `Mailable`:

```
$html = (new InactivityReminder)->render()
```

Comment: This gives me an Exception: Undefined index: secret in Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager.php

Comment: @Chris it's not related to the original question. If you want to help with this, please show the `Mailable`.

Comment: I have added it

Comment: @Chris looks fine. You should check `secret` in mail related config file and in `.env` file because `TransportManager` is trying to use it, but it doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. I was using the mandrill driver. I just don't understand why it needs to access that just for rendering

Answer (score 1):

For fully customizable mails in Laravel, I've had better luck using Mailables rather than Notifiables.  Here's what worked for me:

Mailable class:

```
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;

class MyMail extends Mailable
{
    public function __construct($someData) {
        $this->someData = $someData;
    }

    public function build() {
        return $this->markdown('mail/my-mail-view')
            ->with([
                "someData" => $this->someData
            ]);
    }
}
```

Mail view (resources/view/mail/my-mail-view.blade.php):

```
@extends('mail/mail-layout')

@section('content')
    <p>Hi {{ $someData->first_name }}</p>
@endsection
```

Mail layout (resources/view/mail/mail-layout.blade.php):

```
<div class="myMailBody">
@yield('content')
</div>
```

Mail css file (resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes/default.css):
(assuming you already ran "php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail")

```
.myMailBody {
  // css styles here
}
```

Code in controller:

```
$previewMailHtml = (string) (new \Illuminate\Mail\Markdown(view(), config('mail.markdown')))->render('mail/my-mail-view', [
    "someData" => $someData
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The interface does not provide that functionality. That means relying on it can cause problems when updating Laravel in the future. If this is not an issue for you you can use the [`render()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php#L172) method which returns a View object and then call [`render()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/View/View.php#L82) on that.

So:

```
(new InactivityReminder)->render()->render()
```

alternatively:

```
(string) (new InactivityReminder)->render()
```

as `__toString()` on View will call it's render method.

Comment: Just tested this in 5.5, `render()` returns HTML and not `View` object. `gettype((new InactivityReminder)->render())` returns `string`

Comment: In that case the docblock on the method is outdated and someone should probably make a PR to laravel/framework: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php#L170